# Plotting map in android using google places api suggestion

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am trying to plot a location on android google map v2. As in google map implementation in phone, when a user starts typing, I fetch the location suggestions using places api and displays the same as autocomplete suggestions. [This](http://www.claytical.com/blog/android-dynamic-autocompletion-using-google-places-api) is the tutorial I referred and the places api url I used to fetch suggestions as given in the tutorial is:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Newyor&types=geocode&language=en&sensor=true&key=mykey
```

And a typical response from places api would be:

```
{
"predictions" : [
  {
     "description" : "Pune, Maharashtra, India",
     "id" : "b53b6db33aaf3aa06dc661e9b2631735f3d484f1",
     "matched_substrings" : [
        {
           "length" : 3,
           "offset" : 0
        }
     ],
     "reference" : "CjQwAAAAMoxQRyAwsRv2ORCTdAedR1nQYCErx3mhuiabdfgKaFVn9ptmcBjr6F5zgNpLoF41EhBCLLKBfB7Bm0Vkm6EB7jxKGhSKJt0vahFMJ2GfYLk2uMcBC0Vl5g",
     "terms" : [
        {
           "offset" : 0,
           "value" : "Pune"
        },
        {
           "offset" : 6,
           "value" : "Maharashtra"
        },
        {
           "offset" : 19,
           "value" : "India"
        }
     ],
     "types" : [ "locality", "political", "geocode" ]
  },
  {
     "description" : "Punjab, Pakistan",
     "id" : "97a12ea9bc0c551167da68d14e152d70e68150df",
     "matched_substrings" : [
        {
           "length" : 3,
           "offset" : 0
        }
     ],
     "reference" : "CjQoAAAA0_J5uM7i32DiX4jRXiY8jMp54QBdU7N2vE5XE4IdFbesDW_qdDKQsQ8No7zdjRjFEhC4MJu4F86xTjBYLR9VOEBFGhSELemilA35vFobxi2Z45JvFXM0eQ",
     "terms" : [
        {
           "offset" : 0,
           "value" : "Punjab"
        },
        {
           "offset" : 8,
           "value" : "Pakistan"
        }
     ],
     "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political", "geocode" ]
  },
```

Are there any parameters in the above response which I can make use of in order to plot a map or do I need to make another api call in order to get latitude and longitude of the place which i select from the above "description"  key in the json response? If I need to make an api call again, what are the parameters I need to pass from the above json response.

Or in first place, is there an api already available from which I get the lat, long also along with the places suggestion?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> In first place, is there an api already available from which I get the
>   lat, long also along with the places suggestion?

Yes, for getting (LatLong from Address):

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=NewYork&sensor=true

& for getting (Adress from LatLong):

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.9152555,-73.700272&sensor=true

Comment: Thankyou for your response. But I was asking about an api which would provide lat, long along with the places suggestion at a single go.